# CRUD MySQL com NodeJS: como usar Pool corretamente?

Tags: mysql, node.js

Criei dois arquivo para testar o uso do MySQL com o NodeJS conforme segue abaixo, mas estou achando meio lenta a resposta e acho que estou fazendo algo errado:

**DÚVIDAS**:

1) Essa forma de acessar o banco de dados é a mais correta? Ou seja, toda vez que eu precisar salvar ou acessar algo no banco terei que criar a conexão com `mysql.createPool`, `getConnection` e executar o `release()` para cada operação?

2) Quando executo `retrieve`no meu arquivo `test.js`, recupero os dados usando callback mesmo conforme indiquei?

model.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host     : 'localhost',
  database : 'dbtest',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '123456'
});

exports.retrieveOne = function(id, callback) {
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = ?";
    var params  = [];

    params.push(id);
    sql = mysql.format(sql, params);

    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err)
            console.log('Connection error: ', err);
        else
            connection.query(sql, callback);

        connection.release();
    });
}

exports.retrieveAll = function(callback) {
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM test";
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err)
            console.log('Connection error: ', err);
        else
            connection.query(sql, callback);

        connection.release();
    });
}

//exports.create = function() { }
//exports.update = function() { }
//exports.delete = function() { }
```

test.js

```
var getRow = require('./model.js');

//Retorna todos os registros
getRow.retrieveAll(function(err, rows) {
    console.log('Err: ', err);
    console.log('Rows: \n', rows);
});

// Retorna 1 registro
var id = 2;
getRow.retrieveOne(id, function(err, rows) {
    console.log('Err: ', err);
    console.log('Rows: \n', rows);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No teu `model.js` chamas uma vez `mysql.createPool`. Isso está correto e só acontece uma vez, quando o programa carrega, depois a cada chamada à base de dados usas `getConnection` e `release`.

Para usares o retorno do MySQL deves usar lógica assíncrona, podes usar por exemplo callbacks ou promisses.

Se fizeres isso com promises poderia ficar assim:

model.js

```js
exports.retrieve = function(id) {
  var sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = ?";
  var params = [];
  params.push(id);
  sql = mysql.format(sql, params);

  return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
      if (err) rej(err);
      connection.query(sql, function(err, rows) {
        if (err) rej(err);
        else res(rows);
        connection.release();
      });
    });
  });

}
```

teste.js

```
getRow.retrieve('4').then(rows => {
    console.log(rows);
})
```

Comment: Sergio, perfeito!! Era EXATAMENTE isso que eu precisava, pois não estou retornando os resultados para o browser e sim para um outro script que irá manipular os dados. Só para registro, editei minha pergunta a apresentei a forma como eu já estava fazendo (que funcionou também...). Vou usar dessa forma que você indicou, pois acredito que seja mais correta do que a minha.

Comment: @wBB podes usar como tinhas também. Promisses são mais seguras em caso de erro pois não param o servidor, o erro é controlado de outra forma. Ainda bem que pude ser útil.

Comment: Ah sim, sim dúvida. Já estava até usando o tratamento de erro que acrescentei ao seu código: `getRow.retrievePromise('4').then(_success, _error);` executando corretamente `function _success(data) {
 console.log('DATA: ', data); }` e em caso de erro `function _error(err) {
 console.log('ERROR: ', err); }`

Comment: por gentileza @Sergio, tenho uma dúvida sobre a questão da conexão: eu crio um arquivo a parte chamado "conn.js" por exemplo, em que monto a conexão `var mysql = require('mysql');` e `var pool  = mysql.createPool({......etc, etc`. Aí faço o `require('./conn')` em todos outros arquivos em que vou acessar o banco de dados. Com isso, em todo `require` estou abrindo uma nova conexão em vez de reaproveitar uma conexão já existente, não é?

Comment: @wBB depende de como esse ficheiro estiver. Se fixeres export somente de `pool` então só cria 1 vez. Cada `require` não faz correr o código todo de novo. Testa colocar um `console.log('lalala');` no ficheiro `conn.js` fora do export e dentro do export e vais ver que o que está fora do export só é chamado 1 vez.

Comment: Juro que tentei aqui, mas não consegui montar uma forma em que a criação de uma nova conexão seja executada uma única vez e depois fique disponível para uso. Até tentei usar o `console('DENTRO')` e `console('FORA')` para poder registrar o que estava ocorrendo, mas a coisa não funcionou não...

Comment: @wBB na pergunta tens um ficheiro `model.js`. Esse `var pool  = mysql.createPool..` só é corrido uma vez, independentemente de quantas vezes faças `require` desse ficheiro.

Comment: Vou considerar suas orientações e seguir dessa forma do `model.js` mesmo então (os `consoles.log(dentro/fora)` usei entre esses códigos). Eu mantive `const mysql = require('mysql'); const pool  = mysql.createPool({...etc` depois os exports `exports.retrieveA = function(callback) {...etc, etc` Muito obrigado pelas ajudas!

Comment: Funcionou tudo OK e ficou rápido @Sergio. Obrigado!